# replace a clone element with a new clone element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

With Jquery, I am trying to add a clone element and remove the previously added element. Adding a clone element is working but removing the previously added element is not working (it removes all the clone elements). I am using "not()" function but it is not filtering as I want it to.

I searched through the web but could not find a solution so your help will be greatly appreciated!

--HTML--

```
<div id="clone-container">
   <!--cloned element comes here-->
</div>

<div id="original-container">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <span>Value1</span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <span>Value2</span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <span>Value3</span>
        </li>
    </ul>   
</div>
```

--Jquery--

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#original-container > ul > li').click(function(event){

       //for adding clone elements
       var $selected_clone = $(this).children("span").clone();

       $selected_clone.appendTo("#clone-container > ul > li");


       // for removing previously added elements
       $("#clone-container > ul > li > span").not($selected_clone).remove();

    });
});
```

Comment: So if I click on Value1, then Value2, and then Value3, what should be the content of the clone container?

Comment: so effectively there can only be one element inside the clone-container?

Comment: This doesn't quite make sense; how does the unordered list get into clone-container?  It appears that you want to clone spans from `<li>` elements in one unordered list into `<li>` elements in another list, but `clone-container` doesn't have an unordered list....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out.. http://jsbin.com/uZij/1/

HTML

```
  <div id="clone-container">
    <ul>
      </ul>
   <!--cloned element comes here-->
</div>

<div id="original-container">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <span>Value1</span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <span>Value2</span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <span>Value3</span>
        </li>
    </ul>   
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#original-container > ul > li').click(function(event){

       //for adding clone elements
       var $selected_clone = $(this).clone();
       $selected_clone.appendTo("#clone-container > ul");


       // for removing previously added elements
       $("#clone-container > ul > li").not($selected_clone).remove();

    });
});
```

Comment: Arpit, you need to show your JS too -- you can't rely on jsbin links.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `appendTo` code execution and replace below

```
$("#clone-container > ul > li > span").not($selected_clone).remove();
```

with

```
$("#clone-container > ul > li > span").html($selected_clone.html());
```

Hope this will help !!